# Heroku resets my JSON file

Tags: json, node.js, heroku, deployment, configuration

I have a node.js application that uses a simple JSON file as the model. Since this is an MVP with very limited data storage needs, I don't want to spend time designing and configuring a MongoDB database. Instead, I simply read from and write to a JSON file stored in /data directory of my Node JS application.

However, on Heroku, the JSON file appears to get reset (to the original file I'd deployed to Heroku) every so often. I don't know why this happens or how to turn off this behavior. Any help would be really appreciated, I need to fix this problem within the next four hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku uses an [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-heroku-works#dyno-manager), so that's why it's going to vanish (every 24 hours, or thereabouts).

If you want to store something, you have to use an external backing store.  Adding a free tier MongoDB database shouldn't take more than a few minutes.  [See here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab) or [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongohq) for examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon! Can you please confirm that these steps will get me there - 
1) Setup a MongoDB database locally based on my JSON file (any tips on doing this?)
2) Make changes to my application so that it works with the database
3) Move the database to MongoLab and adjust any necessary configurations

Comment: That'll work - but it looks like you're time constrained, and it's just for an MVP.  So how about setting up the add-on for your app.  Do `heroku config` to grab the database's URL - and connect to it locally.  eg. if you create a MongoHQ add-on and look at the config vars you'll be able to parse out something like: `username:password@hostname:port/appxxxx` then connect locally via `mongo --username username --password password hostname:port/appxxxx`.   Or just use the web tools that MongoHQ provide via `heroku addons:open mongohq` after you provision it (you can create/query/etc.)

Comment: I didn't understand almost any of the steps you mentioned (very knew to this entire stack). I guess I'll work my way through the longer process I outlined earlier. 
If you have any tips (especially with regard to porting a local app that uses mongoDB to heroku), please do share. Thank you so much for your help!